# Hellfire guns as a gadget

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, demon-the-descent

Hellfire doesn't really seem to be a broad range of powers, and I don't see much way of altering it for a gadget.. is the fact that a Hellfire imbued gun wouldn't be able to imbue other guns enough? or should one remove something else, if so what else could be removed?

Comment: I have zero experience with Demon the Descent, but your remark about magic guns not imbuing other guns makes me REALLY want to see a game where that actually happens.  The BBEG has figured out who has the party's Blessed Revolver and is dodging it specifically while just tanking the mundane guns with his evil powers, and the Preacher grins, takes aim, and fires - hitting the Trenches Convert's 9mm semi-auto, which takes on a golden hue as a chorus of angels sound in the background.  The villain's head whips 'round too late, as the 9mm goes off one last time and he falls.  ^_^